# Tornado adds query string to static files path

Tags: python, tornado

When tornado loads a template, the static files path turns into something like this:

```
http://localhost:8888/static/js/jquery-ui.min.js?v=02e1058fd3cb0799867ba932a4ad3b22
```

I use this method of declaring static files:

```
settings = {
    'static_path': os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'static'),
}
application = tornado.web.Application([
        (r'/', MainHandler),
        (r'/login/', LoginHandler),
        (r'/websocket', EchoWebSocket),
        (r'/static/', tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, dict(path=settings['static_path'])),
    ], static_hash_cache=False, debug=True, cookie_secret='salt', **settings)
```

How can I get rid of 'v' variable in path?

Answer (score 2):

the `v` is the static file hash that make by tornado according to content of file.

> The static_url() function will translate that relative path to a URI that looks like /static/images/logo.png?v=aae54. The v argument is a hash of the content in logo.png, and its presence makes the Tornado server send cache headers to the user’s browser that will make the browser cache the content indefinitely.
>
> Since the v argument is based on the content of the file, if you update a file and restart your server, it will start sending a new v value, so the user’s browser will automatically fetch the new file. If the file’s contents don’t change, the browser will continue to use a locally cached copy without ever checking for updates on the server, significantly improving rendering performance.

the `v` used for cache the file in client browser. you can imagine this is a part of file name.

if you don't want this, as tornado said, you can use `nginx` server.

http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/branch2.3/overview.html#static-files-and-aggressive-file-caching